# Measuring the time between two events (pixel color change) using Python freezes everything for some seconds

Tags: python, timer, keyboard, mouse

I've coded a very simple tool for Windows to measure the time between two events in Python 2.7.
Specifically:

1. You point the pixel you want to take as reference with your mouse and you press the 'Left control' key
2. You click (anywhere) when you want to start the timer

The code is as follows:

```
import pyHook, pythoncom
import win32api
import sys
import time
from ctypes import windll
#from PIL import ImageGrab # alternative solution to windll

class Timer:
    def __init__ (self):
        pass

    def Reset (self):
        self.t = time.clock ()

    def Stop (self):
        self.t = time.clock () - self.t

    def Get (self):
        return self.t

def GetPixelColor (x, y):
    dc = windll.user32.GetDC (0)
    return windll.gdi32.GetPixel(dc, x, y)

class Test:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.timer = Timer ()
        self.color = -1
        self.ready = False

    def OnKbEvent (self, e):
        if e.Key == "Lcontrol":
            self.x, self.y = win32api.GetCursorPos ()
            self.color = GetPixelColor (self.x, self.y)
            self.ready = True
            print ("Control point selected")
            print (self.color)

        return True

    def OnMouseEvent(self, e):
        if self.ready:
            if e.Message == 513: # mouse left down
                self.timer.Reset ()
                while self.color == GetPixelColor (self.x, self.y):
                    time.sleep (0.100)
                self.timer.Stop ()
                print "%.5f" % self.timer.Get ()
                sys.exit ()

        return True

t = Test ()
hm = pyHook.HookManager ()
hm.KeyDown = t.OnKbEvent
hm.MouseAllButtonsDown = t.OnMouseEvent
hm.HookKeyboard ()
hm.HookMouse ()

pythoncom.PumpMessages ()
```

The script works, but it takes 5 seconds on my machine (Win7) more than it does normally.
During this time, everything seems to freeze.

Any hint on what I'm doing wrong / how I can improve the script?
TIA

Comment: Note that [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends `lowercase_with_underscores` for functions and methods. `CapWords` should be reserved for classes.

Comment: It sounds like you want to be doing work on a background thread. What you experience seems typical of a Windows application which is doing too much on the foreground thread, causing it stop pumping message momentarily.

Comment: What takes 5 seconds longer than normal?  Does the program work but slow other programs down?  Does it work on other machines?  Did it work previously?

Comment: and don't add a whitespace between a function name and its `(`

Comment: @BrianLyttle is there any solution for this?

Comment: @101100 what I meant was: without using the program timing a particular event takes x; using the program it takes x+5.

Comment: what is `GetPixelColor` actually doing? is it an API call, or implemented using `PIL.ImageGrab`? you're not grabbing the whole screen each .1 seconds just for one pixel, are you?

Comment: @mata wrong copy/paste, sorry. However, no, I'm just grabbing one pixel ;) Editing and adding `GetPixelColor` right away.